# SP2-0310: unable to open file "LOGIN.SQL" from Oracle DB 18c in Docker for Windows container

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, docker-for-windows, oracle18c

In Docker for Windows I installed an Oracle DB 18c XE Linux Docker container by the books:

- Downloaded official sources (from https://github.com/oracle/docker-images)
- Created an image from it
- Created a container:

  ```
  docker run --name $containerName -d -p 15210:1521 -e ORACLE_PWD=$dbPassword -v $dbVolume:/opt/oracle/oradata 'oracle/database:18.4.0-xe'
  ```

When I open SQL*Plus within the container, everything works fine:

```
> docker exec -it DevDB sqlplus sys/pwd@//localhost:1521/xe as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri May 21 19:47:10 2021
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0

SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME
------------------------------
CDB$ROOT
SQL>
```

In my Windows host I installed SQLPlus Instant Client. When I run SQL*Plus from there, I get a warning message telling me that "LOGIN.SQL" cannot be opened.

However, I seem to be able to run queries:

```
> sqlplus sys/pwd@//localhost:15210/xe as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri May 21 21:34:58 2021
Version 18.5.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0

SP2-0310: unable to open file "LOGIN.SQL"
SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME
------------------------------
CDB$ROOT
SQL>
```

What is causing this warning message? How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more testing I now found the answer to my issue:

**Apparently, the reported error is a glitch in the 18.5.0.0 release of SQL*Plus.**

I just updated SQL*Plus to 19.11.0.0, and the warning message is gone:

```
> sqlplus sys/pwd@//localhost:15210/xe as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri May 21 21:53:11 2021
Version 19.11.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0

SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME
------------------------------
CDB$ROOT
SQL>
```